# How do you implement more than one "Employee of" field?

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, fields

How do you implement more than one "Employee of" field?

We have a number of contacts that have multiple jobs.  Ideally we would like to have the Employee Of field have multiple sub fields (primary, secondary, etc) however we are open to all implementation.  How do most people implement other Employers on an individual contact's record?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is allowed to have multiple relationship as employee of for individual with an organization. However you can only have one as a current employer. You can create custom field for relationship with options primary, secondary etc and use it while creating relationship.

HTH

Pradeep